# Searching through a list of dictionaries to see if a key/value exists in any dictionary

Tags: python, list, search, dictionary

so I have a list of dictionaries, 
ex:

```
[{'title':'Green eggs and ham', 'author':'dr seuss'}, {'title':'matilda', 'author':'roald dahl'}]
```

What is the best way to search if outliers by malcolm gladwell exists in any of those dictionaries?

I was thinking of brute force checking each title and author, but I feel like there's gotta be a better way.

Comment: is the list sorted in any way?

Comment: Could you change the structure? `{author: {title: book, ...}, ...}` makes it trivial.

Comment: Do you need them to be dictionaries ? A `set` of tuples (title, author) would probably work faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need *all* key-value pairs to match, you can just use `in` and have the list do the searching for you:

```
if {'title': 'outliers', 'author': 'malcolm gladwell'} in yourlist:
```

Otherwise, with no other indices, you'll have to 'manually' search the list. You can use the [`any` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) with a generator expression to make the test efficient *enough* (e.g. stop searching when a match is found), plus [dictionary view objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) to test for subsets of key-value pairs:

```
search = {'title': 'outliers', 'author': 'malcolm gladwell'}.viewitems()
if any(search <= d.viewitems() for d in yourlist):
```

would match even if dictionaries in `yourlist` have more keys than just `title` and `author`.

You can avoid full scans by using extra indices:

```
authors = {}
titles = {}
for d in yourlist:
    authors.set_default(d['author'], []).append(d)
    titles.set_default(d['title'], []).append(d)
```

creates extra mappings by specific keys in the dictionaries. No you can test for individual elements:

```
if any(d['title'] == 'outliers' for d in authors.get('malcolm gladwell', [])):
```

is a limited search just through all books by Malcolm Gladwell.

The `titles` and `authors` dictionaries map author and title strings to lists of the *same dictionaries*, shared with the `yourlist` list. However, adding or removing dictionaries from one such structure does require updating all structures. This is where a relational database comes in handy, as it is really good at keeping such indexes for you and will automatically keep these up-to-date.